# Bind 9 logging is not working

Tags: rhel, logs, dns, chroot, bind9

I am using RHEL 6.5 server for Master DNS server. And using BIND 9.8.
All are working fine. But customized logging is not working.

Here is my configuration file-

```
logging {
channel general_file {
    file "/var/log/named/general.log" versions 100 size 100m;
    severity dynamic;
    print-time yes;
channel queries_file {
    file "/var/log/named/queries.log" versions 100 size 100m;
    severity dynamic;
    print-time yes;

category default { default_file; };
    category general { general_file; };
    category queries { queries_file; };
};
```

SELinux is disabled. Firewall also disabled.

Ownership of the log file and `/var/log/named/` directory is `named:named`

Please redirect me to any solution as I am working with it for many days.

NB: I am using 2 slave server of this Master. They are having CentOS 7.3 and logging is working fine with this configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution :).

My RHEL 6.5 server is using named chrooted.
So, actual location of all log will be `/var/named/chroot/var/log/named` .

So create `named` directory into `/var/named/chroot/var/log/named`.

```
# mkdir /var/named/chroot/var/log/named
# chown named:named /var/named/chroot/var/log/named
```

Restart named as well.